# Why process in Activiti lose boundaryEvent during lifecycle

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I created diagram which used boundaryEvent to signalize that some action was done.

```
<boundaryEvent id="boundarysignal1" name="cancel" attachedToRef="subprocess3" cancelActivity="true">
 <signalEventDefinition signalRef="cancelApplication"></signalEventDefinition>
 </boundaryEvent>
```

Everything is working ok, but in one moment (I didn't catch it yet), the process loses binding to the event so I can't use flow which related to boundaryEvent at all. Found out that during runtime Activiti creates records into ACT_RU_EVENT_SUBSCR table which holds event subscriptions to appropriate record in ACT_HI_PROCINST table which stores the process instance data. In the same time I see that process is not closed and is alive, the appropriate END_FIELD column is null.

The next code doesn't return anything as event is not bound:

```
final List<Execution> executionList =runtimeService.createExecutionQuery().processVariableValueEquals("VAR_NAME","VAR_VALUE").signalEventSubscriptionName(SIGNAL_CANCEL_PROCESS).list();
```

Meanwhile Process is active as next result is success:

```
final List<ProcessInstance> instances = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().variableValueEquals("VAR_NAME","VAR_VALUE").active().list();
```

**What can be the reason that boundaryEvent is detached from Process?**

Env: SpringBoot 1.3.2 ; Activiti 5.19.0.2

**ACT_RU_EVENT_SUBSCR table(Working example):**
[image]

**ACT_HI_PROCINST table(Working example):**
[image]

**ACT_RU_EVENT_SUBSCR table(NOT Working example, table is empty):**
[image]

**ACT_HI_PROCINST table(NOT Working example):**
[image]

**Process definition diagram:**
[image]

SubProcesses 1,2,3:
[image]

Comment: What's sending cancelApplication signal? Can you post whole process diagram? What happens when the inner process reaches end?

Comment: I meant process.bpmn.xml schema. Are you building these processes using activiti modeler or by hand?

Comment: Q1:"Are you building these processes using Activiti modeler or by hand?"
A1: Am using Activiti visualization plugin to create bpmn.xml shema.
Q2: "What's sending cancelApplication signal?"
A2: It is sending from the code.
Q3: "Can you post whole process diagram?"
A3: Already added diagrams of subProcesses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possibilities is mentioned here:
https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-4591
Release Notes - Activiti - Version 5.20.0
...
Signal and Boundary event subscription are lost when deploying a new process definition version
...

This one was the major reason for us to upgrade to 5.20

Comment: Could you please describe what actions was after you moved to new 5.20 version? As I understand  you already had corrupted Processes by previous 5.19 version. Did migration to new version fixed everything(already damaged processes was fixed only by version upgrade)? Or this defect is just not reproducible?

Comment: Migration did not fix (or change) anything. We had to restart affected processes one by one. Fortunately, they did not include any forms and transient data in outer systems allowed restarts without much troubles.

Comment: Thanks a lot that shared you experience!